# difference in "&" and ":" (method of binding variable)

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

if i run command from Pl-sql command prompt for inserting multiple rows one by one without rewriting statement again & again we can use `&` operator, as shown in below figure.
[image]

if i used GUI method for same purpose, i have to use `:` operator,as shown in below figure
[image]

now my question is-> why we cant use `&` operator in GUI , if we used it gives error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have encountered is a text replacmenet mechanism of SQLplus (and tools that implement the same extension).

You can turn it of with:

```
SET DEF OFF
```

Or you can switch to a different character (the plus sign in this example):

```
SET DEF +
```

The Oracle tool you're using doesn't implement the SQLplus extension as far as I know. But SQL Developer (a free GUI tool from Oracle) does.

Answer (score 4):

`&` operator is not a binding method - it is a [`substitution variable`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch5.htm#CACIFHGB). It has totally different usage scope. Like this:

```
18:46:18 TEST@oars_sandbox> accept table_name char prompt "enter table name > "
enter table name > dual
18:46:42 TEST@oars_sandbox> select * from &table_name
18:46:47   2  /

D
-
X
```

Basically, sql*plus (the command line tool you're using) substitutes these variables in script body with their values at runtime. It gives you huge flexibility for designing your scripts - like, changing your sql*plus scripts (or even anonymous pl/sql blocks) logic on the fly. For instance, that's how I assign a filename to my spool file:

```
col filename noprint new_value spool_file
select '&spoolpath\'
       ||       to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd_hh24mi') 
       ||'_'|| '&_user' 
       ||'_'|| '&_connect_identifier' 
       ||'_'|| '&mysid'
       ||   '.log' as filename 
  from dual;
set termout on
prompt spooling to &spool_file
spool "&spool_file" replace
```

Comment: +1 but I think the OP knows all this, it's just a terminology confusion.

Comment: @JackDouglas maybe. but I don't understand the nature of his question then. why can't we use it in GUI tools? well, because it has never been implemented in GUI tools, what else can we say? :)

Comment: Isn't he saying he *can* do the same thing in the GUI tool, just questioning why the syntax is different? I don't use that tool so I'm not sure if the `:` has the same behaviour as the `&` in SQL*Plus

Comment: @JackDouglas he *thinks* that he's doing the same thing, as it *seems* like he is, but in fact these things are totally different. by using `:` (no matter in sql*plus or in apex workbench) you define variable placeholders, keeping your statement static and avoiding repeating hard-parses while supplying different parameters. `&`, being a sql*plus-specific operator, basically replaces one string literal with another, making your query injection-prone and dooming it to be hard parsed each time it is executed.

Comment: I'm happy to report that this is still a great way to stamp spool filenames in 2023.  I've been searching for this for days...thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Neither method of binding variables is part of the SQL engine: they are both conveniences in the client. As the clients are different, they have different convenience functions.

What you refer to as the "Pl-sql command prompt" is no such thing: it is the prompt of the *client tool* SQL*Plus and not part of the database like the procedural language PL/SQL.

The other tool you are using look like the SQL worksheet in APEX. I suppose if I were to take a guess I'd say they opted for ':' rather then '&' because it was developed many years later and seemed a more natural choice at the time. The Apex interface with Oracle Express Edition is designed to be simple and clean, not to be backwardly compatible with SQL*Plus.